# REST Service PUT , xml payload structure

Tags: java, rest, content-type, payload

for a REST PUT service, im trying to use xml as the payload. My question is can I have the whole payload as xml? or should I do something like `Data=<mydata>......</mydada>`?

basically

```
<mydata>......</mydada>
```

or

```
Data=<mydata>......</mydada>
```

Comment: I think you need to be more specific.  Are you using a particular framework?  The REST paradigm on its own does not restrict message content.

Comment: I would say you have the whole payload as XML, check the HTTP code on the client end to judge the response and parse the content. We do this for our JSON apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can just set the mediaType to be `application/xml` just as you can for json or plain text. The first example is valid XML, second one is not. So the first one can be done.

I am not sure what framework you are using. For example if you plan to use Spring you can take a look at an example [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-spring3webserv/index.html).

The basic idea is that you define the media type to be `application/xml` . You can also specicfy a marshaller/unmarshaller (ie. using JAXB) if you want to marshal/unmarshal from a Java bean.

Comment: so basically they are both valid depend on content-type of the request right?

Comment: @Eatdoku - Correct. You can also make it support json, and plain-text as well as long as you provide a way to parse it.